# Wordpress losing page parent on save

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my Wordpress site - when editing pages the assigned page parent is dropping out. I'm having to manually reassign them in the database.

I haven't installed any new plugins or anything - any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set up a new Wordpress install  on the same server, using the same database server and see if it does the same?

Comment: It's on our shared host with various other WP sites running and they seem ok - it's specific to this site but I can't isolate what's causing it :(

Comment: Any mysql errors being generated when you go to save the file?

Comment: Got it fixed! It was a fix I put in place yesterday. D'oh!

Comment: Care to add an answer to your question (for others coming here with the same issue) ? It would be helpful if you could explain what your issue was, and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Sure. I can't add an answer for now, but in the meantime...

I had an issue whereby the function wp_dropdown_pages() was storing the page ID as option values, instead of the page permalink as desired.

I edited a Wordpress core file for this, so it's not recommended, but I changed this:

wp-includes/post-template.php

Find this line inside function start_el():

$output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"$page->ID\"";

(It should be on line 1415). And replace it with this:

$output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".get_permalink($page->ID)."\"";

Comment: Hmm maybe it would be worthwhile looking more into this, and try to re-trace whatever fix you performed.. as you should ideally want ot leave your core files exactly as they were. Or else you could run into the same problem when the file is next updated by the latest release.